# Unable to boot a fresh Windows 10 installation on M.2 NVMe

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, nvme, m.2

not sure where to ask this. Im struggling to boot/finish installation of Windows 10 on my SSD Crucial 500GB M.2 PCIe Gen4 NVMe P5 Plus - installed in slot M_2_3

[MOBO: ASRock > B660 Pro RS](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B660%20Pro%20RS/index.asp)

I've created USB drive with [MediaCreationTool.](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209)

Turned PC on without touching BIOS.

Instalation wizard started normally, displayed all drives. I selected my NVMe drive but it wouldnt install there as it was dynamic. Using diskpart > clean I formatted and converted entire disk as one standard volume [tried also making it all Unallocated and selecting this as destination with same results] - instalation went good and the next step was restarting.

After restart the installation wizard shows up again and now there are 3 partitions created by the wizard, from which I can choose only the biggest one as destination. If I choose it then I get the notification that system files are in there so they will be moved to old.windows and wizard will copy new ones. The loop goes on like this endlessly.

If I detach USB during restart or disable booting from it in BIOS then I get "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key".

Worth noting: in BIOS default CSM setting is Disabled - with this there is no NVMe drive on bootable drives list, however BIOS "sees" that drive in NVMe section, it displays details about the drive. With CSM enabled I can choose NVMe as bootable device - with USB connected it will go to the installation anyway. With USB detached/disabled its the same "Reboot and Select[...]".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is more, while looking for solutions I've found that its better to have GPT on NVMe drives - using diskpart clean and convert gpt, I created new partition formatted as GPT. From now on nothing changed besides one thing:installation wizard refuses to install on this drive with CSM enabled. Other than that its all the same :(

Also, using only the installation tool I tried removing every partition making the whole disk as Unallocated, checked if its GPT in diskpart, and then choosing it as destination. Results the same

Comment: GPT is not a partition, it's a partitioning type. And yes, not only recommend but *mandatory* for UEFI mode with Windows.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yeah, so now the NVMe drive is partitioned as GPT according to diskpart but still wont boot and continue installation :/

Comment: Check the Boot menu (or equivalent) and make sure the drive priority is given to the drive where you want to install (note: this is a different setting than the OS boot order where "Windows bootloader manager" should appear once installed). Make sure CSM (Legacy) is disabled to assure you're booting the installer in the proper UEFI mode. Preferably have the drive as GPT but entirely unallocated (no partitions), Windows will create all the necessary partitions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto with CSM disabled I cannot choose desired drive as bootable device. Its not listed there.

Comment: also, what I did was to use diskpart > clean and then creating a volume and converting it to GPT, then I used installer menu to remove the partition making entire disk unallocated, then checked with diskpart > detail disk if its still GPT, and then selected the unallocated space for installation location. Same results

Comment: One thing is certain: Booting in Legacy (CSM) mode is dumb since almost a decade ago and guaranteed NOT to install in a NVMe drive. What's really happening I'm not sure but probably you're doing something wrong. Is the NVMe drive the only one you have?

Comment: Its not the only drive I have but its the only one that's connected now. I disconnected other soon after a couple of fails. I can, and already tried, install with CSM disabled as the installer still sees the drive even with CSM disabled [unlike BIOS boot priority list]. However, the results are the same. Actually, since the drive is partitioned as GPT the installer only proceeds with installation if CSM is disabled.

Comment: You may want to reset UEFI to factory defaults and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: What exactly should I try when I reset to default? I mean, I also tried this but Im not sure what troubleshooting steps to take next

Comment: UEFI have a reset command that sets them back to defaults. Use that.

Comment: Do you mean "Load UEFI Defaults" in BIOS?
I've done that multiple times by now.
I've also updated BIOS to most recent version, following the guide loaded defaults again. Still no bootable option available after first step of installation :/